# Java how to reset "set" values after being changed

Tags: java, arrays, reset

```
public static void reset() {
        //goblin
        stats gob = new stats();
        gob.setName("Goblin");
        gob.setHP(15);
        gob.setATK(3);
        //END-goblin

        //orc
        stats orc = new stats();
        orc.setName("Orc");
        orc.setHP(25);
        orc.setATK(5);
        //END-orc

        stats[] enemies = new stats[3];
        enemies[1] = new stats();
        enemies[1] = gob;
        enemies[1].getName();
        enemies[1].getHP();
        enemies[1].getATK();
        enemies[2] = new stats();
        enemies[2] = orc;
        enemies[2].getName();
        enemies[2].getHP();
        enemies[2].getATK();
    }

    public static void fight() {

        //user
        player user = new player();
        user.setP_Name(username);
        user.setP_ATK(atk);
        user.setP_HP(hp);
        //END-user

        //goblin
        stats gob = new stats();
        gob.setName("Goblin");
        gob.setHP(15);
        gob.setATK(3);
        //END-goblin

        //orc
        stats orc = new stats();
        orc.setName("Orc");
        orc.setHP(25);
        orc.setATK(5);
        //END-orc

        stats[] enemies = new stats[3];
        enemies[1] = new stats();
        enemies[1] = gob;
        enemies[1].getName();
        enemies[1].getHP();
        enemies[1].getATK();
        enemies[2] = new stats();
        enemies[2] = orc;
        enemies[2].getName();
        enemies[2].getHP();
        enemies[2].getATK();

        System.out.println("\u001B[32m" + "\nWelcome to Gilenor, " + user.getP_Name() + "." + "\u001B[39m"
                + "\u001B[32m" + "\nIn this world, you will fight monsters consecutively," + "\u001B[39m"
                + "\u001B[32m" + "\nattempting to get through all of them." + "\u001B[39m"
                + "\u001B[32m" + "\nFor each enemy you kill, you will grow stronger." + "\u001B[39m"
                + "\u001B[32m" + "\nFlee to go back to the past enemy, but do not flee on your first enemy!" + "\u001B[39m"
                + "\u001B[32m" + "\nA fair warning to you, " + user.getP_Name() + ":" + "\u001B[39m"
                + "\u001B[32m" + "\nEach monster gets stronger after every win. Good luck!" + "\u001B[39m");

        int answer = 0;
        int d;
        int e;
        boolean alive;

        int i;
        for (i = 1; i < 3; i++) {

            System.out.print("\n");

            System.out.println(enemies[i].getName() + " has appeared!");

            System.out.print("\n");

            alive = true;

            while (alive == true) {

                reset();

                System.out.println(enemies[i].getName() + " stats:");
                System.out.println("Hitpoints[HP]: " + enemies[i].getHP());
                System.out.println("Attack[ATK]  : " + enemies[i].getATK());
                System.out.print("\n");

                if (user.getP_HP() > 0) {
                    System.out.println("\u001B[34m" + "[1 - Attack]" + "\u001B[39m");
                    System.out.println("\u001B[34m" + "[2 - Flee]" + "\u001B[39m");

                    answer = In.getInt();

                    clrscr();

                    System.out.print("\n");
                } else if (user.getP_HP() <= 0) {
                    System.out.println(user.getP_Name() + " has been slain by the " + enemies[i].getName() + "!");
                    return;
                }

                if (answer == 1) {

                    d = enemies[i].getHP() - user.getP_ATK();
                    enemies[i].setHP(d);

                    System.out.println(user.getP_Name() + " strikes the " + enemies[i].getName() + " for " + user.getP_ATK() + " damage.");
                    System.out.println(enemies[i].getName() + " has " + enemies[i].getHP() + " HP remaining.");
                    System.out.print("\n");

                    if (enemies[i].getHP() > 0) {
                        e = user.getP_HP() - enemies[i].getATK();
                        user.setP_HP(e);

                        System.out.println("The " + enemies[i].getName() + " attacked " + user.getP_Name() + "for " + enemies[i].getATK() + " damage.");
                        System.out.println(user.getP_Name() + " has " + user.getP_HP() + " HP remaining.");
                        System.out.println("\n");
                    } else if (enemies[1].getHP() <= 0) {

                        System.out.println("\u001B[32m" + user.getP_Name() + " has slain the " + enemies[i].getName() + "!" + "\u001B[39m"
                                + "\u001B[32m" + "\nYou have gained " + (i * 1) + " attack and " + i * 10 + " HP!" + "\u001B[39m");

                        user.setP_ATK(user.getP_ATK() + (i * 1));
                        user.setP_HP(user.getP_HP() + (i * 10));

                        alive = false;
                    }

                } else if (answer == 2) {
                    if (i == 1) {
                        System.out.println("You ran from your first enemy, tripped, then died! How embarassing!");
                        alive = false;
                        return;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("You ran away, back to the last monster you saw!");
                        System.out.print("\n");
                        i = (i - 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } //fight method
```

In this code, I set values for objects and then put them into an array called

enemies. Afterwards, I change the value of the elements of the objects using the

enemies array. After the "HP" value of the element array reaches zero, it goes

onto the next element. I made it so the user can go back to the previous element

and re-do it, but the element still has the same values as when the user first

altered them. I put all the "set" and enemies arrays which originally defined

the value into a method and tried calling it so it can reset, but I wasn't in

luck. Is there any way I can properly do this?

**EDIT:**

For those wondering, this is my cheap workaround:

```
public static void fight() {

    //user
    player user = new player();
    user.setP_Name(username);
    user.setP_ATK(atk);
    user.setP_HP(hp);
    //END-user

    System.out.println("\u001B[32m" + "\nWelcome to Gilenor, " + user.getP_Name() + "." + "\u001B[39m"
            + "\u001B[32m" + "\nIn this world, you will fight monsters consecutively," + "\u001B[39m"
            + "\u001B[32m" + "\nattempting to get through all of them." + "\u001B[39m"
            + "\u001B[32m" + "\nFor each enemy you kill, you will grow stronger." + "\u001B[39m"
            + "\u001B[32m" + "\nFlee to go back to the past enemy, but do not flee on your first enemy!" + "\u001B[39m"
            + "\u001B[32m" + "\nA fair warning to you, " + user.getP_Name() + ":" + "\u001B[39m"
            + "\u001B[32m" + "\nEach monster gets stronger after every win. Good luck!" + "\u001B[39m");

    int answer = 0;
    int d;
    int e;
    boolean alive;

    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) { //CHEAP WORKAROUND
        //goblin1
        stats gob = new stats();
        gob.setName("Goblin");
        gob.setHP(15);
        gob.setATK(3);
        //END-goblin
        //orc2
        stats orc = new stats();
        orc.setName("Orc");
        orc.setHP(25);
        orc.setATK(5);
        //END-orc
        //pheonix3
        stats pheonix = new stats();
        pheonix.setName("Pheonix");
        pheonix.setHP(75);
        pheonix.setATK(5);
        //END-pheonix
        //ancient dragon4
        stats ancdr = new stats();
        ancdr.setName("Ancient Dragon");
        ancdr.setHP(220);
        ancdr.setATK(13);
        //END-ancient dragon
        //hades5
        stats hades = new stats();
        hades.setName("Hades");
        hades.setHP(500);
        hades.setATK(25);
        //END-hades
        stats[] enemies = new stats[6];
        enemies[1] = new stats();
        enemies[2] = new stats();
        enemies[3] = new stats();
        enemies[1] = gob;
        enemies[2] = orc;
        enemies[3] = pheonix;
        enemies[4] = ancdr;
        enemies[5] = hades;
        enemies[1].getName();
        enemies[2].getName();
        enemies[3].getName();
        enemies[4].getName();
        enemies[5].getName();
        enemies[1].getHP();
        enemies[2].getHP();
        enemies[3].getHP();
        enemies[4].getHP();
        enemies[5].getHP();
        enemies[1].getATK();
        enemies[2].getATK();
        enemies[3].getATK();
        enemies[4].getATK();
        enemies[5].getATK(); //CHEAP WORKAROUND

        System.out.print("\n");

        System.out.println(enemies[i].getName() + " has appeared!");

        System.out.print("\n");

        alive = true;

        while (alive == true) {

            System.out.println(enemies[i].getName() + " stats:");
            System.out.println("Hitpoints[HP]: " + enemies[i].getHP());
            System.out.println("Attack[ATK]  : " + enemies[i].getATK());
            System.out.print("\n");

            if (user.getP_HP() > 0) {
                System.out.println("\u001B[34m" + "[1 - Attack]" + "\u001B[39m");
                System.out.println("\u001B[34m" + "[2 - Flee]" + "\u001B[39m");

                answer = In.getInt();

                clrscr();

                System.out.print("\n");
            } else if (user.getP_HP() <= 0) {
                System.out.println(user.getP_Name() + " has been slain by the " + enemies[i].getName() + "!");
                return;
            }

            if (answer == 1) {

                d = enemies[i].getHP() - user.getP_ATK();
                enemies[i].setHP(d);

                System.out.println(user.getP_Name() + " strikes the " + enemies[i].getName() + " for " + user.getP_ATK() + " damage.");
                System.out.println(enemies[i].getName() + " has " + enemies[i].getHP() + " HP remaining.");
                System.out.print("\n");

                if (enemies[i].getHP() > 0) {
                    e = user.getP_HP() - enemies[i].getATK();
                    user.setP_HP(e);

                    System.out.println("The " + enemies[i].getName() + " attacked " + user.getP_Name() + " for " + enemies[i].getATK() + " damage.");
                    System.out.println(user.getP_Name() + " has " + user.getP_HP() + " HP remaining.");
                    System.out.println("\n");
                } else if (enemies[1].getHP() <= 0) {

                    System.out.println("\u001B[32m" + user.getP_Name() + " has slain the " + enemies[i].getName() + "!" + "\u001B[39m"
                            + "\u001B[32m" + "\nYou have gained " + (i * 1) + " attack and " + i * 10 + " HP!" + "\u001B[39m");

                    user.setP_ATK(user.getP_ATK() + (i * 1));
                    user.setP_HP(user.getP_HP() + (i * 10));

                    alive = false;
                }

            } else if (answer == 2) {
                if (i == 1) {
                    System.out.println("You ran from your first enemy, tripped, then died! How embarassing!");
                    alive = false;
                    return;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("You ran away, back to the last monster you saw!");
                    System.out.print("\n");
                    i = (i - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
} //fight method
```

Comment: you need immutable data structures so that you can snapshot your states !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arrays nor any collection have an UNDO method, you need to design your own where you hold the last state of the data container and restore it as required whenever you need it

Comment: How would I make this container?

Comment: memento pattern!!

Comment: @RaminAmiri You need two Collections, one "current" and one "old". When someone makes a change on the current, you first update the old collection.

Comment: @JeremyGrand I see. Should I do research on these java "collections" then?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I researched it a little bit, and it looks very interesting, thanks you for the great suggestion. However, I found a cheap workaround for the time being as I'm still new to Java coding and need to dip my feet further into the water to go to those levels.

Answer (score 0):

So many things here just don't make sense:

In the reset function:

```
// This stats[] array is local, it won't effect the one out side of the function...
stats[] enemies = new stats[3]; // Why size 3 if only use 2? first index is 0.
enemies[1] = new stats(); // This new stats instance will be override next line, so it have no effect.
enemies[1] = gob; // here you share reference to the gob instance, not copying it. so any change on 'enemies[1]' will in fact be apply on gob.
enemies[1].getName(); // Do nothing...
enemies[1].getHP(); // Do nothing...
enemies[1].getATK(); // Do nothing...
enemies[2] = new stats();
enemies[2] = orc;
enemies[2].getName();
enemies[2].getHP();
enemies[2].getATK();
```

And this is just by glancing on the first function, checking the rest make even less sense. sorry, but if you have more specific question I will be happy to answer.

Comment: Yeah, at this point of code that I've provided is when I was desperate. Don't mind this, I already knew it wasn't going to work. I've found a different solution, of where I copy and pasted all of the sets and enemies right after the for loop so that it automatically resets. It cheap, but works.